# how to handle background task?

Tags: ios, background-task

I am new in iOS.
I am trying to implement upload data in uitableview one by one row.
for that i am using background task.

using following code.

```
-(void)MethodUploadBgTaskAssign
 {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSString *responseString = [self MethodlblUploadClicked];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                           {
                              if([responseString isEqualToString:@"UploadSuccess"])
                               {
                                  [self ReloadTblData];
                                  [self ContinueUploadData];
                               }
                           });
        });
}

-(void) ReloadTblData
 {
    if([dataArr count]>0)
    [dataArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];

     [uitblData reloadData];
  }

 -(void) ContinueUploadData
 {
    if((dataArr count]>0)
    [self  MethodUploadBgTaskAssign];
 }
```

My problem is uploading data in table after some time table reload with empty data
because all data uploaded at that time.

I want show updated ui after uploading each cell in table.

What will be necessary changes in code?
appreciate for help.

Comment: are you trying to implement lazy loading?

Comment: no I am trying to upload data in each cell after upload data in first cell delete that cell and show updated UI and then upload first row data continue that till finish all row data.

Comment: Did you implement this method in cell or controller?

Comment: I am using uitableview in view controller

Comment: Where did you implement the above method? In tableviewcell or view controller?

Comment: in reload data method i am deleting uploaded data from array and then reload table. and  in ContinueUploadData I am calling method MethodUploadBgTaskAssign.

Comment: Share some code snippets in your post. I am not able to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66925/discussion-between-adeel-ur-rehman-and-stack).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are updating the table - but in the wrong thread (hence the table never actually appears to update).  You need to use performSelectorOnMainThread to update the UI.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ReloadTblData:) // Update the table on the main thread
                       withObject:nil
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I think this should work - give it a go!